# Incremental MySQL reading using Logstash

Tags: mysql, logstash

I have a MySQL database which data is added to it over the time. And I want to transmit the data into a Elastic using Logstash to generate some report.

Is there a way to memorize MySQL's the last transmitted record and resume the logging process once a new record is inserted?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a MySQL input for logstash. Have you already looked at [logstash-input-jdbc](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc)? Doesn't it meet your needs?

Comment: I can't be sure if the mentioned plug-in is what I'm look for or not since it has got no doc on how to use it. What I look for is a MySQL input for Logstash with one important feature; I need it to support adding new data to MySQL even when it's done logging all the data. So once new data are introduced to MySQL, it must detect them and log them in the output. Does it do this?

Answer (score 4):

In order to incrementally update the data in the Elasticsearch, we have to have a column in the database such that it can be used as a reference. And also we have to set up a schedule to run the configuration file again and again.

Let’s say you want to send the newly added rows to Elasticsearch and you have an id field which gets auto incremented in the table. Then you can tell the Logstash to fetch only the records which value of the id is greater than the id value of the previously fetched record. In order to tell Logstash to track a column and which column to track we have to use the

> tracking_column and use_column_value

options in the JDBC section. After that the configuration file will look like the following.

```
input {
  jdbc {
  jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
  jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"
  jdbc_user => "DBUSERNAME"
  jdbc_password => "DBPASSWORD"
  statement => "select * from TABLE where id >:sql_last_value"
  tracking_column => id
  use_column_value => true
  #I have scheduled this to run in every second
  schedule => "* * * * * *"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "index"
    document_type => "type"
    user => "userName"
    password => "password"
  }
  stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug 
  }
}
```

> :sql_last_value

contains the value of the id of the record which has been sent previously. But with an id field, you can only send the records which are newly added. If you want to update the documents in the Elasticsearch which were sent previously according to the changes done to the records in the database, you have to use a row_update_time column (Or something similar to use as a reference) that gets updated every time you change the records in the table. You can find more information about that [here](https://medium.com/@erangadulshan.14/pushing-relational-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash-jdbc-input-plugin-48af81ed1000).

Answer (score 0):

The logstash jdbc{} input can maintain state for subsequent queries.  Some examples are given in [their documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html), but the general idea is that you can use `sql_last_value` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
statement => "SELECT id, mycolumn1, mycolumn2 FROM my_table WHERE id > :sql_last_value"
```

and tell logstash which field to use to update `sql_last_value`:

```
tracking_column => id
```

If you're using an id column like this, you also need to set

```
use_column_value => true
```

If you're using a datetime field, then `use_column_value` should remain the default of `false`.